# Sink or resend android received broadcast

Tags: java, android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I have an application that expects SMS messages in certain formats. If a SMS message meets specific criteria set out by my app, I want to prevent the re-broadcast of the SMS, otherwise allow it to proceed to other BroadcastReceiver (like the default SMS reader).

Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    String msg = processMessageFromIntent(intent);
    if(needed(msg)){
     //prevent propagation;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to set a hight priority for the receiver and call abortBroadcast.

Answer (score 0):

This will only work if the intent has been sent with `Context.sendOrderedBroadcast`
as per [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#abortBroadcast%28%29).

So, you have to check with the broadcast you want to handle.

Comment: You are right. I didn't bother with that in my answer because the Receiver in question ( for new sms ) is an OrderedBroadcast.